# Error when filtering HRU QSWAT+

Tags: qswat

I am trying to create HRUs when I get this error (see image).

[image]

I have created my own usersoil table, because the ones that were there were too general so I found all the data I needed and I created the usersoil table.
I have no problems creating the HRU, but when I try to filter them (it does not matter what type of filter) i get the error of the image. What does this error mean? What can I do to solve the problem?